# Why is it illegal to take the address of the "this" pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I try to find address of `this` pointer, but this code is showing a strange
error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
    public:
        void test()
        {
            void *address_of_this =&this;
            cout<<address_of_this<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{   Base k;
    k.test();

    return 0;
}   //error non-lvalue in unary'&'
```

Can you explain this error ?
Also point that what is illegal in taking address of `this`?

Comment: Try adding a space after the = sign

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`this` is a pointer containing the address to the "current object". It is not a variable that is stored somewhere (or could even be changed), it is a special keyword with these properties.

As such, taking its address makes no sense. If you want to know the address of the "current object" you can simply output:

```
std::cout << this;
```

or store as

```
void* a = this;
```

Comment: Finally.. the voice of reason.

Comment: In standardese: `this` is an rvalue (and not of class type), so it doesn't have an address.

Comment: In Standardese again, `this` is _prvalue_ - _pure-rvalue_.

Answer (score 9):

Quoting the 2003 C++ standard:

> 5.1 [expr.prim] The keyword `this` names a pointer to the object for which a nonstatic member function (9.3.2) is invoked. ... The type of the expression is a pointer to the function’s class (9.3.2), ... The expression is an rvalue.
>
> 5.3.1 [expr.unary.op] The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a **qualified_id**.

To put it simply, `&` requires an lvalue. `this` is an rvalue, not an lvalue, just as the error message indicates.

Answer (score 1):

This is an artificial restriction.

Compiler optimizations aside, `this` acts as a hidden pointer parameter to member functions. (Yes, it could sit in a register, but so can regular pointer parameters).

There's no reason this couldn't have worked. My best guess is that nobody thought it would be useful, so they made `this` a prvalue, which essentially prevents taking its address.

Comment: That something does not have a persistent address/location for one to take need not be reason enough not to take its address. A vector could get reallocated and `.data()` does offer its current address .

Comment: @Tryer Ultimately, inability to take addresses of rvalues is an arbitrary language limitation, desiged to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. Nothing would stop us from defining `&` to materialize prvalues into xvalues, which actually exist in memory, and then allowing `&` to work on xvalues. It would just be hard to use safely, because the resulting pointer would become dangling at the end of the full-expression that produced it. Here's an interesting example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mvqvc7836

Comment: I don't think that it is computed on the fly. I rather think that the non-static member function takes a reference to the object that it is called upon as a hidden parameter. So it probably is stored in memory/register but handled as an rvalue to not let the programer interfere with it (reassignment, etc.).

Comment: @tweekz Yes, fair enough. I meant it's computed before calling the member function, but then there's no reason to not be able to take its address *in* the member function. I've rewrote the answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I myself am researching this topic at the moment (privately). There are resources that confirm this idea, like [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/this-pointer?view=msvc-170). But then again, this is a compiler-specific statement. I guess the language spec is not as specific about it to allow for different implementations. Unfortunately I think you got to purchase it to read it.

Comment: @tweekz Nobody pays for the standard, since the drafts are freely available, and have no meaningful differences to the real thing. [There's the current draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/), and you can find snapshots for specific C++__ versions. Don't read too deep into it, trying to account for all the possible weird implementations leads nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the **current** object by using it's address.

In your problem, there are *two* errors:

- `this` is **not an *lvalue***.

  The `&` requires an *lvalue*. *lvalue*s are those that can appear on on the left-hand side of an assignment (variables, arrays, etc.).

  Whereas `this` is a *rvalue*. *rvalue*s can not appear on the left-hand side (addition, subtraction, etc.).

  Reference: [C++ Rvalue References Explained](http://www.thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).
- A **hidden** error which I'd like to also mention is thus:

  `address_of_this` is actually receiving an address of an address.

  Basically, `&this` is translated into something like `&&object` or `&(&object)`.

Basically, think of `this` as `&object` (but only to remember because it is not that true).

Comment: It isn't very clear, what you wanna imply in your 2nd error.